# Grouped by set of columns, first non zero value and one of all zeros in a column needs to be flagged as 1 and rest as 0

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Org1': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4], 
                   'Org2': ['x','x','y','y','z','y','z','z','x','y','y','z','x','x'], 
                   'Org3': ['a','a','b','b','c','b','c','c','a','b','b','c','a','a'], 
                   'Value': [0,0,3,1,0,1,0,5,0,0,0,1,1,1]})
df
```

For each unique set of "Org1, Org2, Org3" and based on the "Value"

1. The first non zero "value" should have "FLAG" = 1 and others = 0
2. If all "value" are 0 then one of the row's "FLAG" = 1 and others = 0
3. If "value" are all NON ZERO in a Column then first instance to have FLAG = 1 and others 0

I was using the solutions provided in 
[Flag the first non zero column value with 1 and rest 0 having multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61297678/flag-the-first-non-zero-column-value-with-1-and-rest-0-having-multiple-columns/61297776#61297776)

One difference is in the above Point 2 isnt covered

"If all "value" are 0 then one of the row's "FLAG" = 1 and others = 0"

Comment: Could you please also include any attempt you made/error traceback you've received? At the moment this reads like a "complete the assignment for me" request.

Comment: I have this 

m = df['Value'].ne(0)
idx = df['Value'].where(m).groupby([df['Grp'],df['Org1'],df['Org2']]).idxmax()
df['FLAG'] = df.index.isin(idx).astype(int)

But this doesnt address my 2nd
If all "value" are 0 then one of the row's "FLAG" = 1 and others = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify linked solution with remove `.where`:

```
m = df['Value'].ne(0)
idx = m.groupby([df['Org1'],df['Org2'],df['Org3']]).idxmax()
df['FLAG'] = df.index.isin(idx).astype(int)
print (df)
    Org1 Org2 Org3  Value  FLAG
0      1    x    a      0     1
1      1    x    a      0     0
2      1    y    b      3     1
3      1    y    b      1     0
4      2    z    c      0     0
5      2    y    b      1     1
6      2    z    c      0     0
7      2    z    c      5     1
8      3    x    a      0     1
9      3    y    b      0     1
10     3    y    b      0     0
11     4    z    c      1     1
12     4    x    a      1     1
13     4    x    a      1     0
```